# When rotating simulation, content does not resize. Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11

When I run my app simulation in Xcode 11, it works fine (portrait or landscape). But when I rotate, it doesn't resize to the appropriate constraints I set for that orientation.

[Sim in portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrv2N.png)

[Sim in Landscape after rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18LOu.png)

[Image of constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bx4k.png)

If I stop the app from running in the background and route the simulation then open it, then it works fine.

How can I resize the content while the device rotates?

Comment: Ive used the constraints in the storyboard. I will update the post to contain the image of my constraints

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lays in your `height` and `width` constraints.

Try removing `MCC.width = 812` and `MCC.height = 376`. The remaining constraints you have set for your label will keep it in the centre of your `Video layer` view.

Also try removing `height = 2000` on your `Video Layer` view as the remaining constraints you have set should keep it bound to the edges of its view.

The problem with setting height and width constraints explicitly is when you rotate the device the height and width of the device changes. For example when you run your app (starting in portrait) you have a max height of 896 and width of 414 points on an iphone 11. But when you rotate it to landscape those values swap so you now have a max height of 414pt and a width of 896 points.

Run your app in portrait, after you rotate it have a look in `Debug` -- `View Debugging` -- `Capture View Hierarchy` (in the Xcode menu not the simulator menu). I think you will find that your `Video layer` is extending past the superView

Do you want your `Video layer` content to cover the whole screen? if so in the attributes inspector set `Content Mode` to `Aspect Fill` this will clip some of the content. If you want all of the content visible set it to `Aspect Fit`.

Comment: I have removed the constraints you told me about (except the height = 2000 because it says it is required. I also tried the aspect fill and aspect fit for the Video layer and it still does not work.

Comment: Ok, so you want the Scroll View to be able to scroll to a max of 2000? also in landscape do you want the Video layer to fill the screen or keep the same dimensions it has in portrait (in which case you would need to scroll to expose the rest of it) Let me know what your desired layout is and i'll update the answer for you.

Comment: i would like the scroll view to stay as 2000 and I want the video layer to take up the full screen ( whether in portrait or landscape) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to use constraints or auto-layout to pin the subviews (text, image, those subviews that aren't displayed properly after rotation to the parent view (the main `UIView` of your `UIViewController` for example).

There are plenty of places you can do so. These are some of the examples:

- In **Interface Builder**: You'd need to either use

  1. auto-layout to define how each subview can stretch, and where to anchor the subview. Use the following to achieve this:
     [image]
  2. use constraints to do the pinning and anchoring:

  **How to add**

  [image]
  [image]

  **How to Inspect**

  [image]
- In **code**: You can use

  1. constraints to pin your view to superview.

  ```
      titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: closeButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
      titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: closeButton.topAnchor).isActive = true
      titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
      titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
  ```

  2. Using Frames and sizes:

  ```
  titleLabel.frame = mySuperView.frame
  ```

  For code layout/constraints, if you're anchoring the view, I found it best to add it when adding the subview to the superview (in `viewDidLoad` or `init...`), but if you're working with sizes (`widthAnchor` and `heightAnchor`), OR if you're using frames and size, layout update methods (`layoutSubviews`, `didLayoutSubviews`, `transition...`, ...) are the best place, as they get updated when rotation changes.

NOTE: I used xcode 11.7 to make the screenshots, xcode 12 changed some icons so they will look slightly different. However, functionality is the same.

Comment: thank you for the response, I appreciate the detailed answer. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I don't know whats going on and it's very frustrating

Comment: @JonathanSoliman what is that constraint with 2000 height? it's strange to have a constraint with 2000 value? if you remove that, would it solve the problem?

Comment: I have a scroll view with the height of it being 2000. I also want the video layer to be at the top of the scroll view taking up the entire screen, and as you scroll. the video will move up with the scroll view.